# Gramatical Structure - "Need I justify myself any further?"

Tags: sentence-structure

Is it correct to say:

> Need I justify myself any further?

to make the same sense as:

> Do I need to justify myself any further?

Is that even grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *1.  Need I justify myself any further?*
>
> *2.  Do I need to justify myself any further?*

Both are fine; it's a free choice. “Need” is a dually-classified verb belonging to both lexical and auxiliary verb classes.

As a lexical verb, it exhibits subject-auxiliary inversion when forming questions, as in 2. (note the inversion of subject "I" and auxiliary "do").

As a modal auxiliary verb, "need" has no subject-auxiliary inversion, as in 1.

Comment: +1 But is this a case of homophony as opposed to polysemy? (just wondering ...)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is grammatically correct. In English, *modal auxiliaries* are cast into interrogative moods without using "do". For example:

- "I should go to the movies" becomes "Should I go to the movies?"
- "He must go to school" becomes "Must he go to school?"
- "You might be mistaken" becomes "Might you be mistaken?"

["Need" is considered a semi-modal verb](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/need). As that page shows, the question form without "do" is acceptable grammar. However, it is somewhat archaic and formal. Informally, as you suggest, "Do I need to justify myself any further?" would be far more common.